# I am trying to set a condition on the value of an input component in react (MERN)

Tags: reactjs, input, conditional-statements, frontend, mern

I am working on an Instagram clone in MERN to practice and learn.
The registration form has input, and you can register either with an e-mail or a mobile number. I am trying to make a ternary operator in the value of the input component, but I get errors when I run the code.

Validate Email function:

```
const validateEmail = (userOption) => {
    let checker = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
    return checker.test(userOption);
}
```

Input component

```
<label htmlFor="email" />
<input type="text"
    name="email"
    value= { validateEmail(registerOption) ? {user.email} : {user.mobile} }
    onChange={onChangeHandler}
    placeHolder="Mobile Number or Email" />
```

It does not recognize user.email or user.mobile, even though when I have it without the ternary it does. (only for email or only for mobile works)
I am also not sure if I have to change htmlFor as well.

Thank you!

Comment: What happens if you ditch the `{ }` around `user.email` and `user.mobile`?

Comment: Error goes off, but does not let me type anything on the input

Answer (score 3):

As explained by the other answers, you don't need to use `{}` to wrap `user.email` or `user.mobile` again. However, your `onChangeHandler` is only going to update the `email` field and not the `mobile` field since you are updating based on `event.target.name`.

I would suggest, you validate the input on click of a button instead on switching the value of `<input />` on every user input.

Add a state (let's say `userInput`) and update that in the `onChangeHandler`.

```
const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState('');
const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
    setUserInput(e.target.value);
    ....
```

When the Sign up / Sign In button is clicked, we would validate the `userInput` and proceed accordingly.

```
const onSubmit = () => {
   const isEmail = validateEmail(userInput);
   if (isEmail) setUser({...user, email: userInput});
   else setUser({...user, mobile: userInput});
   // proceed to signin / signup or show an error message
}
```

Your Input will accordingly change to

```
<input
    type="text"
    value={userInput}
    onChange={onChangeHandler}
    placeHolder="Mobile Number or Email"
/>
```

**Alternatively**

If you want to update the `user.email` or `user.mobile` on every user input, you can use the following `onChangeHandler` method -

```
const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
    const userInput = e.target.value;
    const isEmail = validateEmail(userInput);
    if (isEmail) setUser({ ...user, email: userInput, mobile: '' });
    else setUser({ ...user, mobile: userInput, email: '' });
}
```

Your Input will accordingly change to

```
<input
    type="text"
    value={user.email || user.mobile}
    onChange={onChangeHandler}
    placeHolder="Mobile Number or Email"
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things here:-

1. Remove the { } around `user.email` and `user.mobile`.
2. Don't depend on `name` attribute of input field for your scenario. Let it be something like "contact" unrelated to your js code. Also directly use `user.email` as parameter to `validationEmail` function.

```
const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
        const {value} = e.target;
        const isValidEmail = validateEmail(value);
        const user = isValidEmail?{...user,email:value}:{...user,mobile:value}
        setUser(user);
    }
```

Validate Email function:

```
const validateEmail = (userOption) => {
    let checker = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
    return checker.test(userOption);
}
```

Input component

```
<label htmlFor="contact" />
<input type="text"
    name="contact"
    value= {validateEmail(user.email)?user.email:user.mobile}
    onChange={onChangeHandler}
    placeHolder="Mobile Number or Email" />
```

Behaviour:- When the email is valid, the input box will show that as the value. As soon as it gets invalid the input box will show mobile number as the value. See if this is what you intended!

Comment: Thank you, but it takes the value as it was an email when I try to input a mobile number

Comment: Do you know what can be happening?

Comment: @MoisesRodan Hey it’s my bad. Actually I am not clearing the email field when I am setting the mobile field and vice versa in your onChangeHandler. So even though you’re entering mobile number, the previously saved email is being validated each time. I think himayan has given a nice solution for that. Use that.

Answer (score 1):

The {} is a special syntax which is used to evaluate JS expression.

So when you write `value= { validateEmail(registerOption) ? {user.email} : {user.mobile} }` , you don't need to wrap `user.email` and `user.mobile` in `{}` again, as they will be treated as JS value since they are already wrapped inside curly brackets.

Answer (score 1):

The `value` prop  should look like so:

```
value={ validateEmail(registerOption) ? user.email : user.mobile }
```

Using the statement `{user.email}` will be parsed as

```
{ // scope
  user.email // expression
}
```

Comment: Hi, I already tried that value prop, but it makes the input unavailable to write anything

Comment: So you need to fix `onChangeHandler` logic